# Not able to bold first column in table. I have tried the normal methods

Tags: html, css

I need to bold the first column (inside of the tbody tag) in the table I am creating. For some reason the normal methods won't work.  I have tried the  tag and the font-weight: bold, as well as first-child. I suspect it has something to do with the rows being generated through a function in TS? I tried to set the text to bold in the function, but couldn't seem to do that either. I am very new to this, so maybe I am just missing something simple? Any help would be appreciated!

The table generates normally by the way.

```css
tbody:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-editable table-striped table-hover table-  sortable" style="width:100%">
  <thead class="thread-dark">
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 90px;">Team</th>
      <th style="width: 90px;">Category</th>
      <th style="width: 90px;">SWAG</th>
      <th style="width: 90px;">Completed</th>
      <th style="width: 90px;">Remaining</th>
      <th style="width: 90px;">% Over/ Under SWAG</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <ng-template ngFor let-team [ngForOf]="gemEngineeringTeams">
    <tbody team-list-row [engineeringTeam]="team"></tbody>
  </ng-template>
</table>
```

Comment: Your selector should be: `tbody tr td:first-child`.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for "any `tbody` that is also a `first-child` of it's parent" (`tbody:first-child`).

You want to look for any `td` that is a first-child inside of tbody:

```
tbody td:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Or, if you expect there to potentially be `th` in addition to `td`, then "any first child that is inside a row inside of tbody":

```
tbody tr :first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```